# What is an elegant way to distinguish a normal link from a bookmarklet link?

Tags: hyperlinks, bookmarklet

How do you visually tell to your user that a given link is a *bookmarklet* so it should not be clicked but just bookmarked?
Is there a proper and recognized icon to use to alert the user that a given link is a bookmarklet?

Comment: I've always seen bookmarklets explicitly explained in a paragraph before/around the bookmarklet link. Unlike links there's usually at most one bookmarklet on a page and they require explicit explanation. What's your situation where you think such elaboration is unwanted?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/ in the homepage, I would like to keep it clean adding some visual tips that tell the user that the third link should be dragged and saved and not clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it look more like a button, show hand (drag) cursor when mouse is over. But you’ll need to add explanations anyway, because bookmarklet are not so common in the web.

[image]
[image]

UPD: from new delicious redesign:
[image]

Comment: The dotted border makes it look like an area to drop something into rather than something you can drag. I feel Boxee's is better.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have to elaborate too much in the home page. Just don't make the link the bookmarklet itself, but rather let a click on this link open a tiny popup that explains "bookmark this.. blah blah.." and gives the actual link to bookmark.

This also has the added advantage that you can give the first link a descriptive name like "Acme Bookmarklet", which you can't do with the actual bookmarklet link because that's the description the browser is going to give the button.

So, bait and switch, basically.